# Typescript accept object parameter as long as it contains a key

Tags: typescript

I have a function that is shaped like:

```
type itemType = {
    id: string;
    [x: string]: unknown;
}
// my function
(item: itemType) => {do stuff here}
```

I want to use this function and pass an object that at least contains an id key, is there a way to do this? I am trying to do it this way but get errors:

```
type bigItemType = {
    id: string;
    name: string;
}
(item as bigItemType) => { console.log(item.name) }
```

I'm able to bypass it by casting it in the body of the function but is it possible to do it in the parameters?

error:
`Type 'bigItemType' provides no match for the signature '(item: itemType): void'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. But you can simply extend another type with `&` operator:

```
type itemType = {
    id: string;
    [x: string]: unknown;
}

type bigItemType = itemType & {
    name: string;
}

const func = (item: bigItemType) => { console.log(item.name) }
```

Now `bigItemType` extends `itemType` and adds `name` to it.

You can test it [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAlsEFsAq5oF4oG8CwAoKBsAJgFxQDOwATjAHYDmA3HoVANoAeZlNDAumQCutANa0A9gHdazXAF88eUJCgAjGPQCS8ZKigY4iFCoBkWFoVoBDBBG7U6TPAtx4AxuNqUoAM2Fv9KAAKQwQydS0dYwgASn0APiwoDy9xABsIADo08XoQnUzrWzi5IA).

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me. I was trying to do `item as bigItemType` inside the parameter when I should've done `item: bigItemType` like you did.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an intersection and union:

```
type ItemType = { id: string; } | { id: string; } & { [key: string]: unknown; }
```

Explanation @ [Tree of locations object type declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71246876/tree-of-locations-object-type-declaration)